# Why is numpy.dot() throwing a ValueError: shapes not aligned?

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I want to write a program that finds the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix by iterating over a guess (Rayleigh quotient iteration). I have a test matrix that I know the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of, however when I run my code I receive

> ValueError: shapes (3,1) and (3,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

By splitting each numerator and denominator into separate variables I've traced the problem to the line:

```
nm=np.dot(np.conj(b1),np.dot(A,b1))
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as npl

def eigen(A,mu,b,err):

    mu0=mu
    mu1=mu+10*err

    while mu1-mu > err:

        n=np.dot((npl.inv(A-mu*np.identity(np.shape(A)[0]))),b)
        d=npl.norm(np.dot((npl.inv(A-(mu*np.identity(np.shape(A)[0])))),b))

        b1=n/d
        b=b1

        nm=np.dot(np.conj(b1),np.dot(A,b1))
        dm=np.dot(np.conj(b1),b1)

        mu1=nm/dm
        mu=mu1

    return(mu,b)

A=np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,1],[3,2,1]])
mu=4
b=np.array([[1],[2],[1]])
err=0.1

eigen(A,mu,b,err)
```

I believe the dimensions of the variables being input into the `np.dot()` function are wrong, but I cannot find where. Everything is split up and renamed as part of my debugging, I know it looks very difficult to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mathematical issue is with matrix multiplication of shapes (3,1) and (3,1). That's essentially two vectors. Maybe you wanted to use the transposed matrix to do this?

```
nm = np.dot(np.conj(b1).T, np.dot(A, b1))
dm = np.dot(np.conj(b1).T, b1)
```

Have a look at the documentation of [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) to see what arguments are acceptable.

> If both a and b are 1-D arrays, it is inner product of vectors (...)
>
> If both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication (...)

The variables you're using are of shape (3, 1) and therefore 2-D arrays.

Also, this means, alternatively, instead of transposing the first matrix, you could use a flattened view of the array. This way, it's shape (3,) and a 1-D array and you'll get the inner product:

```
nm = np.dot(np.conj(b1).ravel(), np.dot(A, b1).ravel())
dm = np.dot(np.conj(b1).ravel(), b1.ravel())
```

Comment: Ah yes I understand why that's an issue. If they're both vectors, why doesn't np.dot return the dot product of the two? Or am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Comment: An array with shape (3,1) is a 2d array, where matrix multiplication applies.

Comment: Ah, so taking the transpose and matrix multiplying is equivalent, it just needs the extra step because of how numpy views "vectors"?

Comment: You could also "squeeze" the (3,1) matrices to make them become (3,) which IS a vector [Numpy Squeeze Docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html)

Comment: Good point! I'm not actually sure. I just wanted to toss it up there to show OP that a (3,1) might make sense to us as a vector (we implicitly drop the 1), but to a machine (3,1) and (3,) are different